# Install XCode on MacOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: xcode

I'm getting an error where I can't install XCode because my MacOS version is 10.15 when the requirement is version 11 or higher.

I don't want to upgrade my mac version because this is a company laptop so my other development tools might get affected.

How do I create a workaround for this?

Comment: *I can't install XCode…* Which Xcode?

Comment: Installing Xcode 12 is no problem with oSX10.15

Comment: Xcode 12.5.1 @vadian

Comment: can you give me a link where i can download? I've been trying other links but it's not opening after download @ClausBönnhoff

Comment: Why don't you use the AppStore?

Comment: It says there that it requires macOS 11. I have macOS 10.15 Catalina and I don't want to upgrade because my other developer tools might get affected. @ClausBönnhoff

Comment: You tried this? https://xcodereleases.com

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: I made it an answer. Please accept it. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing! :))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can download all versions of Xcode from this site

https://xcodereleases.com

Comment: Older Xcode versions are also listed on the Apple Developer site https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

However, there the downloads do not mention OS version they support.

Answer (score 42):

The latest version of Xcode you can run on Catalina (10.15.4) is Xcode 12.4  and Command Line Tools 12.4.

You can download older versions of Xcode and the Command Line Tools from Apples developer site.
https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

You can check which Xcode version is supported by your OS here; https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/